# Does my second local player have a different MMR?

Tags: steam, rocket-league

I play both solo and split-screen for competitive doubles, and have noticed that my primary account `Player` and my second controller `Player(2)` have different ranks `Veteran` & `Pro` respectively.

Right now they are both in `PROSPECT II`, and my win rate on `Player` is much higher than `Player(2)`.  Do I have two MMRs on my account? Can I be placed into two leagues separately?  Does playing split-screen have any impact on moving up or down leagues?

I did notice that we often face two players in different leagues such as one `PROSPECT ELITE` and one `UNRANKED`.  Is this just a coincidence?

Answer (score 2):

This post is a bit dated now, but it had a great explanation on how the game actually determines your "true skill":

[Check Your MMR](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/3nn1by/everything_you_need_to_know_about_your/)

It seems entirely possible that the game creates two separate "profiles" for your respective players. Therefore, both Player and Player(2) would both impact your placement in ranked "Doubles." However, each account would be impacted separately. For instance, if you played by yourself and used matchmaking for a "Doubles" partner, only the Player would be impacted by those matches. When you play split-screen, both Player and Player(2) would be impacted.

This means that it's also probably pretty likely that the game has assigned two separate MMRs for Player and Player(2). If you're playing on PC, the post I linked you above might help confirm that, if you can find the log files and make a determination between Player and Player(2).

Just my two cents.

Comment: Excellent read, but my logs don't seem to have the SkillMU. Edit: They seem to have patched it from the logs.